# Multiple statements in a for loop (1084 error)

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to do a binary search in a for loop. However, flash does not like the following for loop.

```
for(var select:int = Math.floor((min + max / 2)), var turns:int = 0; turns < input.length / 2 + 1; turns++, select= Math.floor((min + max / 2))){
    if(input[select] > want){
        max = select;
    } else if (input[select] < want){
        min = select;
    } else {
        return select;
    }
}
```

On the first line I get 1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before var. I think I know why (I'm using , to separate the different statements), but how do I fix it? ; won't work since it's what the for loop uses.

```
( var select:int = Math.floor((min + max / 2)) ; var turns:int = 0); turns < input.length / 2 + 1; //etc
```

does not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply ditching the second `var` (after the comma) <strike>should work I believe</strike> will do it:

```
for(var select:int = Math.floor((min + max / 2)), turns:int = 0; turns < input.length / 2 + 1; turns++, select= Math.floor((min + max / 2))){
    if(input[select] > want){
        max = select;
    } else if (input[select] < want){
        min = select;
    } else {
        return select;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about declaring multiple variables with , not needing another var.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to do this as a for loop? This would work much better as a recursive function.

Here it is as a for loop.  Try pulling the select variable outside the scope of the for loop.

```
var select: int = Math.floor((min+max/2));
for(var turns:int = 0; turns < input.length / 2 + 1; turns++){

    if(input[select] > want){
        max = select;
        select= Math.floor((min + max / 2))
    } else if (input[select] < want){
        min = select;
        select= Math.floor((min + max / 2))
    } else {
       return select;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm doing codeKata two, which is about doing binary searches in different ways. :)